# Is it possible to track 404 images with google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, 404

I know I can track 404's using google analytic's, but our images are served from a CDN and we can't control the 404 page that is served from the CDN.

Is there a way that I can detect missing images and track that via google analytics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I the end I went for this approach:

```
$("img").error(function () {
    var src = $(this).unbind("error").attr("src");
    pageTracker._trackPageview("/404-image?path=" + src + "&from=" + window.location.href);
});
```